# capturar texto de un archivo txt en dropbox por medio de un link web python

Tags: python

Hola quisiera saber como puedo obtener un dato de un archivo txt que subi a mi dropbox con BeautifulSoup de python pero me devuelve el valor en blanco [], aqui dejo el codigo.

```
r = requests.get("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wrnp2s659z830iintexr5/direccion_mac.txt?rlkey=1xyyu8nhrjhqq79xoeooj4i1a&dl=0")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="highlight")
print(divs)
```

y este es e codigo html

```
<body class="texthtml">
  <div class="highlight"><pre><span></span>d8:c4:97:6d:10:a3
  </pre></div>
</body></html>
```

Cómo capturo lo que está dentro de la etiqueta `<pre>` gracias

Comment: l problema que estás experimentando puede deberse a que la página de Dropbox que estás intentando analizar con BeautifulSoup no es una página HTML estándar, sino que se carga dinámicamente con JavaScript. BeautifulSoup no puede interpretar JavaScript, por lo que no puede ver el contenido dinámico de la página

Comment: muchas gracias me toco hacerlo manual en el codigo agradezco su tiempo y colaboracion.